# Corsair Virtuoso Sidetone on MacOS

Tags: mac, microphone

I am setting up a new **Corsair Virtuoso headset** on my **Mac** computer. The audio and the microphone from the headphones works on both wired and wireless mode. However, **I can't get the SideTone feature to work** on either mode.

I am seeing an alert on the iCUE software which is telling me "to fully enable all audio features of your CORSAIR headset, please allow CORSAIR system extension in Security & Privacy settings. System restart may be required for the changes to take effect."

The only place I can find anything related to Corsair in the security & privacy settings is the iCUE request in "accessibility" (picture attached). I have restarted the computer and reinstalled all drivers.
I couldn't upload screenshots to this message, so I've included two via this google drive link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bMSd3G2AGeiGyu4113Zn1Hdm6n0ygCbG?usp=sharing

Anyone have any suggestions for possible solutions to **enable Sidetone on my Corsair Virtuoso headphones on my Mac?**

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: The image is unreadable so thje question makes no sense

Comment: To include pictures click on the little image icon next to the {} on top of the editor box.

Answer (score 1):

on Security and Privacy, on the General tab there should be a message saying something like Corsair was blocked.... enable developer access to Corsair or so, enable that and restart it should work afterwards, this worked for my void elite